# Would deuterium or tritium be a better rocket fuel?

Tags: physical-chemistry, rocket-science, propulsion, combustion

Im not that scientifically literate but through my basics as hell understanding  of  chemistry  is that denser=better  wouldn't the denser forms of hydrogen be better for fuel  since they would weigh slightly more and  would produce  more thrust  for less space.

Comment: tritium decays, and deuterium extraction would increase the cost. cost effectiveness is important for fuel.

Comment: I think that this should be migrated to space.stackexchange where it is more likely that people familiar with rocket engines will answer properly. I would say that becuase enthalpies of combustion are close but the molecule of D2O is heavier the resulting specific impulse will be lower. And the main advantage of H2 is high specific impulse (whereas it's not so good for thrust, that's why it used in high stages and Shuttle had solid rocket boosters)

Comment: Hydrogen fueled rockets usually burn their propellant fuel-rich, meaning they don't release enough oxygen to burn all the hydrogen. This is in part to keep engine temperatures in check, but more so because lighter molecules are better for converting heat to momentum. The specific impulse of deuterium would therefore be lower than for hydrogen. If you think about it, you're adding more inert neutrons to your fuel which don't add any energy, so more dead weight (although not entirely dead, it is still used as reaction mass).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we take a cubic metre of the liquified gas. For hydrogen this would be about $71$ kg, which is $35200$ moles. Deuterium is denser so a cubic metre of deuterium is $162$ kg. However the molecular weight of deuterium is twice as great as the molecular weight of hydrogen, so the number of moles of deuterium in our cubic metre is only $15\%$ greater at $40200$ moles.

The enthalphy of combustion of hydrogen and deuterium is about the same, so by using deuterium our cubic metre gives us 15% more energy. However it weighs twice as much as the hydrogen, and for a typical rocket the majority of the weight is the fuel so this extra weight would be a significant penalty.

Offhand I don't know what fraction of the weight of a typical rocket would be the hydrogen, but I doubt the extra weight would be worth the $15\%$ increase in energy.